# How do I monetize Adobe AIR apps?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I have made an AS3 game in flash, and I have published it as an .apk , but how can I add ads to it? When I search on the Internet everyone is talking about some programs on how to rotate ads, and I don't really understand it. I just need to know if it's possible to do something that is not against the terms of the ads network. Also I don't need in-game purchases or something similar.

Comment: You could use Appodeal for example. Very high revenue, great support, great SDK http://appodeal.com/+register

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at using the AdMob Adobe AIR native extension for Android. [Click here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/admob-ane-android.html) for a nice tutorial on how to integrate it into your application using ActionScript 3.

Comment: hello, I have downloaded admob ane from code.google.com but I keep getting errors, like namespace in the descriptor file is invalid, or cannot parse the descriptor file... do you know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Luka You should post this as a separate question. Dallas187 adequately answered your question here (the AdMob ANE is the go-to ad supplier for AIR apps), so you should accept it and post another question regarding issues with getting it to work. Try to keep each question focused on just that one question on SO.